# The 'law' is a tag of off-topic-osity

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, off-topic

The [law](/questions/tagged/law) tag is nearly completely off-topic. I've taken a swat with my available vote inventory; would anyone else care to join in?

Comment: And wow, you can really tell the EU Cookie law .. well .. happened.

Comment: I haven't seen any evidence @Tim. Absolutely no one has come to give me cookies... Do you know where they are?

Comment: I've gone through all the open ones and voted to close all save 2. They were on-topic just mistagged. One point people closing: Not all are off-topic, some are just old not constructive etc...

Comment: I went through a bunch of them too. Note, some of the questions revolving around an OSI approved license are in the on topic realm, e.g. 'can I mix this code with this code' and the like. I _think_ I caught the rest that were just tagged incorrectly.

Comment: I think we need a place to send the valid ones first. The ones with up-votes about the EU cookie law all seem to be valid. They just don't need the tag.

Answer (score 3):

Why not setting it as a synonym of [legal](/questions/tagged/legal)?

Comment: Right. There're stuff about software licensing and a lot of off-topic as well. Perhaps it opens a door to non constructive, debate-like questions. But for those who don't ("how will my program's license interact with this or that"), what should OP use?

Comment: I'd be all for burninating that one too. Anyone who takes legal advice from anonymous strangers on the internet is a fool, and we shouldn't be encouraging them to ask.